# Hide text characters which do not belong to scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Let's say I have a piece of code like this:

```
<div id="myModule">
    <span data-ng-bind="var1"></span> | <span data-ng-bind="var2"></span>
</div>
```

Since I'm using `ng-bind`, instead of the `{{}}` notation, nothing will be printed on screen until the controller updates those scope variables. And the controller updates the variables after an AJAX request with `$http`, and sometimes that takes a while.

The issue here is that for a few milliseconds (sometimes a second or 2), the user will see a lonely `|` character on screen and that's not really desirable. I tried to use `ng-cloak` in various places but none worked.

What's the best solution to avoid stuff like this from appearing on screen before the controller has finished updating all scope variables? Preferably, without having to concatenate the `|` in the controller.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `ng-show`?

```
The following will not show until var1 and var2 is set
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-show="var1 && var2">
  {{var1}} | {{var2}}
  <br/>
  <span ng-bind="var1"></span> | <span ng-bind="var1"></span>
</div>
```

This is the demo. http://plnkr.co/edit/qncwYKqeO2lcoMM4Y0QQ?p=preview

The problem with this approach is that if var1 is set to null, whole block will disappear. Hope that is not your case.

Comment: I don't really like this solution, but I'm going to use something similar (using `ng-show` and only display when all data has been populated in the controller).